# Why does Jaime disrespect Jory?

Tags: game-of-thrones

On this video, we can see Jory and Jaime having a nice talk like  old friends. Jaime says Jory don't need to apologize, then they remember the siege at Pyke, where they both fought for the same side.
[Jory and Jaime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=583fSgvqPQU&t=1m50s)

Then suddenly, Jaime remembers he should't be friendly with Jory... and disrespects him. At this time the Lannisters and the Starks did not have the "Tyrion problem" between them. So I don't see any reason for Jaime being unfriendly with Jory.

This questions here reveals more details about History between the Lannisters and the Starks : [What was the original cause of enmity between Stark and Lannister?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96284/what-was-the-original-cause-of-enmity-between-stark-and-lannister)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jaime is not necessarily unfriendly *because* it is Jory.

Jaime is "guarding" King Robert, who at the moment is having his way with some * ahem * Ladies. Jaime is Cersei's brother and Cersei is also Robert's Queen.

Jaime is upset that Robert is disrespecting his sister and family name. Jaime is upset at the situation and that Jory is now another first-hand witness to it. I would say Jaime doesn't suddenly remember that he should be unfriendly with Jory as much as a couple whores come suddenly barging out at that moment.

As Jaime says in the scene,

> He likes to do this while I'm on duty. Makes me listen as he insults my sister.

Also, at the end of the day, there is no love lost between the Starks and Lannisters going back to before the Rebellion. Specifically Ned and Jaime never saw eye to eye after Ned found Jaime in the throne room having freshly slain the Mad King.

Comment: Jaime was being unfriendly to _Ned_... Jory just happened to be the proxy.

Comment: @KutuluMike That could be a part of it. I think Jamie is just generally grumpy at the situation to begin with.

Comment: So there is no bad feelings between Lannisters and Starks ? I remember Ned being sarcastic about Jaime's unscratched and shiny armor... I don't rememberr exactly the scene.

Comment: @Bebs Quite the contrary. There are * a lot* of bad feelings between them. "No love lost" means that the people didn't like each other to begin with.

Comment: @Bebs Several things suggest he has for years felt like he's constantly being judged by people like the Starks (e.g. in the Season 3 bathtub scene) and is insecure about his own status and achievements (e.g. his white book entry, most scenes with Brienne, every time he's called a "glorfied sentry"...). He lashes out when the indignity plus his insecurities all get to him - the once-celebrated "golden child" Jaime Lannister, now expected to play message boy between some non-famous nobody serving the self-righteous, judgemental Starks, and a drunken, whoring oaf openly dishonouring his sister

Comment: Jory's a vassal of Lord Stark and not of sufficient status for Jaime to treat him with respect.